# TYPO3 v7, SOLR and CentOS7 problem with openSSL

Tags: solr, openssl, centos, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have TYPO3 v7.6.32 and SOLR-Apache v6.6.2 and TYPO3-SOLR-Extension v6.5.1

I always get the following error while indexing

```
    TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception: PHP Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in
```

I have a CentOS v7 and create a cert.pem with `openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem`

In php.ini stands `openssl.cafile   /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem`

```
plugin.tx_solr {
   solr {
      scheme = http
      host = localhost
      port = 8983
      path = /solr/test/

   }  
}
```

httpd24 and php restarted.

Where did I make my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I see your solr configuration there, that solr is running on HTTP (NOT HTTPS).
Therefore, I'm not sure why you need a certificate.

Therefore, you could try to disable the SSL connection to your solr index from typo3, somehow.

What I can tell you, is that if you try to connect to solr via php-curl, you would just disable CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.
Simply set that 0.

That also happens when the solr (remote) server doesn't have a valid certificate.